# Filtering ListView which is part of a ViewPager Fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I recently converted my application from using Activites and TabHost to using Fragments and ViewPager from the Android Compat Library for API v4
I was able to fix/resolve most problems but am unable to retain the previous behavior with filtering text in ListViews using the [`setTextFilterEnabled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setTextFilterEnabled%28boolean%29) method.

My `ViewPagerAdapter` contains Fragments which each have a `ListView`. As users swipe through the `ViewPager`, I would like the currently active Fragment's ListView to filter text as users type, just like I was able to do with the TabHost-Activity model. Currently, it looks like the first Fragment's ListView will respond correctly, but if I swipe to the next Fragment and try to filter its ListView, the filtering will still apply to the first one. If I swipe past the first two and then filter, the results are non deterministic. The currently active Fragment will never apply the filter. Sometimes a neighboring fragment will, sometimes it won't.

I tried to fix this by adding custom callbacks which let me monitor which Fragment is currently visible, and which are hidden. When a fragment becomes visible as the main Fragment of the ViewPager, I set the `setTextFilterEnabled` on its ListView to `true`, and set all others to `false`. This didn't seem to help at all (I verified that I was toggling the flag correctly for the right Fragments).

I suspect this needs some kind of deeper integration with ViewPager, but I can't really figure out what I need to wire up. Any ideas on how I can make this work? I'm happy to muck with the ACL code if needed.

Comment: it will help if you could post relevant snippets of what you have done before, and what you do now.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the method [onPageSelected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageSelected%28int%29) extending `OnPageChangeListener`. Perhaps you already do this. From there you can set the adapter to the current ListView or requery your cursorAdapter if that's the case. Note that the Adapter used must implement the Filterable interface.